# Showing input when CheckBox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a contact form, I have two inputs, of `type="checkbox"`; the first one is email, and is already checked, but I want to uncheck this, in the event that the user picks the "Phone" option, and show the phone input in which to enter the phone number.

Here's the code:
[at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlejandroMAL/dL36kccw/)

I hope you guys can help me, I'm still a js newbie but I have learnt a lot.

HTML
                
                
                    Name *:

```
                <label for="">Email <span>*</span>:</label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email (Required)">

                <label for="">Got a question? <span>*</span>:</label>
                <textarea name="" id="" rows="1" placeholder="Got a question? (Required)"></textarea>

                <label for="">Best form to contact</label>

                <div>
                    <p>Email: </p>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="email" id="email2" checked>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <p>Phone: </p>
                    <input type="checkbox">

                    <input type="text" placeholder="Give us your phone" id="phonecheck" class="NoDisplayed"> 
                </div>

                <div class="SendButton">
                    <a href="" id="send">Send</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#ChatContainer').hide();
    $('.NoDisplayed').hide();

    $('#ChatToggle').click(function(){
        $('#ChatContainer').toggle('slow');
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Comment: I left a jsfiddle in the question :)

Comment: I know, I read your question. Now please put your code in it.

Comment: Why are you using checkboxes for mutually-exclusive options?

Comment: A radiobox could in fact make the thing easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest associating your 'preferred contact' choices together, using radio-inputs (since 'preferred' is an exclusive choice to make, whereas 'acceptable' might include all possible options), giving:

```
<label for="">Best form to contact</label>
<div>
    <p>Email:</p>
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email" id="email2" checked="checked" />
</div>
<div>
    <p>Phone:</p>
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Give us your phone" id="phonecheck" class="NoDisplayed" />
</div>
```

Which would work with the following jQuery:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="contact"]').on('change', function(){
    $('#phonecheck').toggle(this.value === 'phone');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dL36kccw/9/).

It's worth also noting that your HTML is somewhat problematic; your `<label>` elements weren't associated with *any* (let alone 'specific') form-elements; you were using a `<label>` simply to provide a form's section-name (for which the `<legend>` attribute should be used, within a `<fieldset>` grouping). That said, I've corrected your HTML *and* moved the phone-number entry box outside of the `<div>` that was containing the checkbox (and now contains a radio-input), to reduce the jarring effect of the `<form>` suddenly being displaced. There's *still* a bit of a jump, but not quite so profound.

Here's the amended HTML, which still works with the above jQuery:

```
<div id="ContactForm">
    <div id="ChatToggle">
        <p>Contact Us</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ChatContainer">
        <form action="">
            <label>Name <span>*</span>:
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name (Required)" />
            </label>
            <label>Email <span>*</span>:
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email (Required)" />
            </label>
            <label>Got a question? <span>*</span>:
                <textarea name="" id="" rows="1" placeholder="Got a question? (Required)"></textarea>
            </label>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Best form to contact</legend>
                <div>
                    <label>Email:
                        <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email" id="email2" checked="checked" />
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Phone:
                        <input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone" />
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Give us your phone" id="phonecheck" class="NoDisplayed" />
            </fieldset>
            <div class="SendButton">    <a href="" id="send">Send</a>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dL36kccw/10/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-equals (`attribute="value"`) selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- HTML Elements:

  - [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset).
  - [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).
  - [`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend).
  - [`<input />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Thanks for all the advices, however, this was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**

```
var $checkPhone = $('#checkPhone');
var $checkMail = $('#checkMail');
var $phonecheck = $('#phonecheck');

$checkPhone.change(function(data) {
    $checkMail.attr("checked", false);
    if (this.checked) {
        $phonecheck.show();
    }
    else {
        $phonecheck.hide();
    }
});

$checkMail.change(function(data) {
     $checkPhone.attr("checked", false);
     $phonecheck.hide();
});
```

- remove the class `NoDisplayed` form the phone element and repelace it by `style="display: none;"`

http://jsfiddle.net/dL36kccw/8/

**Addition:**
Doing such stuff with jQuery is not the easiest. You often end up in placing some DOM manipulations in several places which makes the code less maintainable (like the `$phonecheck.hide();` in this case.

I can strongly recommend to take a look into [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) or some other UI framework. A good list of frameworks + examples can be found on [todoMVC](http://todomvc.com/). I think Knockout is the best for many cases. Backbone is very competitive, too. But in the end you need to find one that reflects your needs and style.

**Edit:** Fixed the bug with unchecking the pohne.

Comment: I agree to Slippery that using change would be better than handling click :) Since it would also work for toggeleing using the keyboard.

Comment: This suits perfectly as I needed, thank you so much.

Comment: I'm having some issues, the first one, if I click on the phone checkbox again it unchecks but the input doesn't hide, I tryed an if else but it doesn't work, honestly I don't understand very well the change method, and one more question, if I want to click outside of the toggle how can I make it hide the contact form?, sorry for so many questions :S

Comment: Change simply calls the callback function as soon as the value changes. Why not take a look into the API: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: You are right, there was a bug when you uncheck the phone box. See how I fixed it.

Comment: Oh and a comment on the hiding when clicking the background: Basically I know two options: (1) Track clicks on the background with the `click` event (might need some html code as well). (2) Track the focus in the form (might be more complicated with jQuery). But please put it into another questions to get an full answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to handle the change event of the phone checkbox:

```
$("#chkPhone").on("change", function () {
    $("#email2").prop("checked", !($(this).is(":checked")));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dL36kccw/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
// I have just added id (id -->"phone" to checkbox for corresponding phone number text box and    added style="display:none;" to phone number text

<label for="">Email <span>*</span>:</label>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email (Required)">

<label for="">Got a question? <span>*</span>:</label>
<textarea name="" id="" rows="1" placeholder="Got a question? (Required)"></textarea>

<label for="">Best form to contact</label>
<div>
<p>Email: </p>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="email" id="email2" checked>
</div>

<div>
<p>Phone: </p>
<input type="checkbox" id="phone">

<input type="text" placeholder="Give us your phone" id="phonecheck"   style="display:none;"> 
</div>
<div class="SendButton">
<a href="" id="send">Send</a>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

// please try this script

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>

$('#phone').click(function(){
if($('#phone').is(':checked'))
{
$('#phonecheck').show();
}
else
{
$('#phonecheck').hide();
}
});
</script>
```